# XML feed into Rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm doing some work with [Adcourier](http://api.adcourier.com/docs/index.cgi?page=jobboards_overview). They send me an xml feed with some job data, i.e. `job_title`, `job_description` and so on.

I'd like to provide them with a url in my application, i.e. `myapp:3000/job/inbox`. When they send their feed to that URL, it takes the data and stores it in my database on a Job object that I already created.

1. What's the best way to structure this? I'm quite new to MVC and i'm not sure where something like this would fit.
2. How can I get an action to interpret the XML feed from an external source? I use Nokogiri to handle local XMl documents, but never ones from a feed.

I was thinking about using http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post to handle the post. Doest anyone any thoughts on this?

Comment: If it is a typical feed (e.g. Atom or RSS), then you request it. Feeds don't actually get pushed.

Comment: As mentioned on the Adcourier page, the feed gets sent or submitted from their end.

_The data will be sent to the 3rd party interface over a HTTP POST_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your job controller add a action inbox which gets the correct parameter(s) from the post request and saves them (or whatever you need to do with it).

```
def inbox
  data = Xml::ParseStuff(params[:data])
  title = data[:title]
  description = data[:description]
  if Job.create(:title => title, :description => description)
    render :string => "Thanks!"
  else
    render :string => "Data was not valid :("
  end
end
```

Next set your routes.rb to send posts request for that URL to the correct location

```
resources :jobs do
  collection do
    post 'inbox'
  end
end
```

Note I did just made up the xml parse stuff here, just google a bit to find out what would be the best solution/gem for parsing your request.

Comment: Thanks Vikko, that has certainly helped clarify the structure. And yeah I'm happy to research XML stuff. It seems request.raw_post() will open the data and Nokogiri will let me parse it, so all seems good on that front. 

Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `data = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)` for instance.